# How to print part of string which is of kind mentioned below

Tags: perl

`.a_b_c(x_y_z)`, this is my string so the question is how to get only `a_b_c`

Thanks in advance

Comment: @the beginning I have a . and I want see only a_b_c

Comment: $key = substr($_ ,0, index($_, '('));

Comment: but I am getting the beginning dot also which I don't want

Comment: Beginning dot? I don't even see a period/full stop in your example.

Comment: sorry that's by mistake the string is like .a_b_c(x_y_z), with 
 
 
$key = substr($_ ,0, index($_, '('));  I am getting .a_b_c but I want only a_b_c

Comment: Then start `substr` at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: ya I tried but its printing even the bracket that I    .a_b_c(

Comment: That's because the third parameter is the length, not the index of the character to stop at. You probably want: `print $1 if /^\.([^(]+)/;`

Comment: `my ($result) = m/(\w+)/;`

Comment: Thanks Jacob ,Sobrique and choroba its working:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to use a regex pattern for this

```
use v5.10;

my $s = '.a_b_c(x_y_z)';

my ($ss) = $s =~ /(\w+)/;

say $ss;
```

#### output

```
a_b_c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $s = '.a_b_c(x_y_z)';
print substr $s =~ s/\(.*\)//r, 1;
```

The substitution removes the parenthesised part, `substr` removes the dot.